# Does Google Cloud Dataflow optimize around IO bound processes?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Python beam.DoFn which is uploading a file to the internet. This process uses 100% of one core for ~5 seconds and then proceeds to upload a file for 2-3 minutes (and uses a very small fraction of the cpu during the upload).

Is DataFlow smart enough to optimize around this by spinning up multiple DoFns in separate threads/processes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dataflow will run up multiple instances of a DoFn using python multiprocessing.

However, keep in mind that if you use a GroupByKey, then the ParDo will process elements for a particular key serially. Though you still achieve parallelism on the worker since you are processing multiple keys at once. However, if all of your data is on a single "hot key" you may not achieve good parallelism.

Are you using TextIO.Write in a batch pipeline? I believe that the files are prepared locally and then uploaded after your main DoFn is processed. That is the file is not uploaded until the PCollection is complete and will not receive more elements.

I don't think it streams out the files as you are producing elements.